# How to set multiline text using Text widget?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to show a text in multiple lines, I mean like this:

"I am a text

and I finish here"

When I try to do that, I see a bar that says "Right Overflowed by 443 pixels".
I have this UI structure:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    child: Image.asset('images/place.png'),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15.0),
                      child: Text(
                        _placeCard.description,
                        style: TextStyle(),
                        softWrap: true
                      )
                  )
                ],
              ),

            ],
          ),
        )
    );
  }
```

Where _placeCard.description is something like : "nce thethethe  the the the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to"

Could someone help me or give me any feedback?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Wrap your `Text` widget using a `Flexible` widget.

like,

```
//updated read: aziza comment
  Flexible(//newly added
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15.0),
      child: Text(
        _placeCard.description,
        style: TextStyle(),
        softWrap: true
      ),
    )
  )
```

A simple example in below link:

https://gist.github.com/Blasanka/264510a0e7e5aaa151f02ada19fd466d

**Update:**

Above solution wraps the `Text` widget but in your question code snippet, the problem is you are using two `Column`s inside a Row and you havent added constraint. So, the easy solution to wrap those two `Column` widget using `Flexible` widgets.

like below,

```
Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: <Widget>[
    Flexible(
      child: Column(
      //...
      ),
    ),
    Flexible(
      child: Column(
      //...
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: if you need the container , use it around it. Basically Flexible must be a direct descendant of Column or Row

Comment: I tried with that, with the Flexible, and it throws an exception "Incorrect use of pParent Flexible widgets must be flexible", it was about the padding, so, I removed it, but I got the same result, text is not multiline

Comment: Using Flexible as Container parent, I'm getting same issue.
Could be it something about a parent node?

Comment: @JosephArriaza you can refer link that I gave you, code snippet that I have provided should work

Comment: I think I got it, I changed the third node, the Row one, I used Table there, and create use a TableRow, and it works in that way

Comment: JosephArriaza: you dont have to add Table to avoid this error, look at the updated section in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your text widget in Expanded class and set it's flex factor. It will force the text to fit within the container.

```
    Card(
          color: kBoxColor,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.description),
              SizedBox(width:20.0),
              Expanded(
                flex: 30,
                child: Text(
                  // Extremely long text,
                  style: kAnsTextStyle,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```